# How to get a variable from complex attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html looks like this:

```
<input class="car-type-input" name="carType[bmw]".../>
```

How to get a variable in javascript which contains `bmw` using jQuery?

Html CANT be changed!

Current javascript:

```
  $('.car-type-input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var carType = $(this).attr('name')..// Get the variable
        alert(carType);
      }
```

Comment: `var type = $(tr).attr('name')..match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]` - where `tr` is a reference to the tr element

Comment: where and when do you want to do this... how do you know which `tr` to target

Comment: Your suggestion would work, however I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution, without involving regex.

Comment: You can use substring like `var ct = $(tr).attr('name'), type = ct.substring(8, ct.length - 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```js
$('.car-type-input').each(function() {
  var name = this.name;
  var regex = name.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
  var substring = name.substring(8, name.length - 1)
  snippet.log('regex: ' + regex);
  snippet.log('substring: ' + substring);
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="car-type-input" name="carType[bmw]" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr[carType]').attr('carType')
```

Comment: Yes bc you edited your post and changed the HTML completely.
But there are plenty of other solutions posted.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/3xdecwco/4/

HTML:

```
<input name="carType[bmw]">...</input>
```

JS:

```
alert($("input").attr("name").split('carType[')[1].split(']')[0]);
```

Comment: Sorry, html can`t be changed.